# Looping through Lemmas in NLTK Wordnet

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

Have a script for getting italian synonyms from Wordnet like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

it_lemmas = wn.lemmas("problema", lang="ita")

hypernyms = it_lemmas[0].synset().hypernyms()

print(hypernyms[0].lemmas(lang="ita"))
```

When I do the looping I get message `that list indices must be integers or slices, not Lemma`

How should I do the looping to get not only one value ([0]) but all the values in this dictionary (the amount can be different) and print them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

it_lemmas = wn.lemmas("problema", lang="ita")

for i in range(len(it_lemmas)):
    hypernyms = it_lemmas[i].synset().hypernyms()

    for i in range(len(hypernyms)):
        syn = hypernyms[i].lemmas(lang="ita")
        print (syn)
```